# IMPORTHTML/ IMPORTXML to get Image in Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula

Only found a couple of articles on using these two Google Spreadsheet functions to import/scrape images from pages, but the solutions didn't really work for me. I'm looking to apply it to Wikipedia or DBpedia structure. I don't necessarily want the image imported into Sheets, it would be enough to get a TRUE / FALSE if there's a pic in the first place, but since what I've tried is forever "Loading..." can't tell if it's working or not.

```
=IMAGE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(A1,"//a/@href"),"where Col1 contains 'image'"))
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Biden <- this one would get TRUE (as right side table contains image)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Sartori <- would get FALSE (as it doesn't have image)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A1, "//tbody/tr[2]/td/a/img/@src"))<>""
```

[image]

also if you get this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hover-zoom%20/pccckmaobkjjboncdfnnofkonhgpceea?hl=en

you can just hover over link to see the image:

[image]